# Exclude Current and Sticky Post

Tags: wordpress, sticky

On a single Post page I have a side bar displaying up to three other, related posts. How can I exclude both Sticky Posts and the Current post?

I know how to exclude the `Current post` and how to exclude `Sticky Posts` by using post_not_in in a `WP_Query`, see code example below. But I guess you can not use `post__not_in` twice in the same query. Any suggestions?

```
$current_post_ID = get_the_ID();

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )
            'post__not_in' => array($current_post_ID)
        );
```

Comment: Used the solution as explained here: [WordPress Stackexchange forum][1]. Thanks for all the replies!


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140000/exclude-current-and-sticky-post?noredirect=1#comment200219_140000

Answer (score 0):

The `post__not_in` is an *array()* and uses post `ids` (numbers only).
There is no need to use it twice, use it like that:

`//First build the array of excluded posts
$excluded_posts = array_push(get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) , $current_post_ID);`

`//Then use it in the option
'post__not_in' => array( $excluded_posts )`

Note the `array_push()` PHP function, this will add the current post to the end of the sticky posts array, which is then passed to `'post__not_in'` option.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

                      $sticky =array(get_option('sticky_posts'));

                       // (add post id on sticky_posts option like ex. 485,458,256)

                      $current_post_ID = get_the_ID();
                      array_push($sticky,$current_post_ID);

                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'order' => 'DESC',
                            'orderby' => 'date',
                            'posts_per_page' => 3,
                            'post__not_in' => array($sticky)
                        );
                        query_posts($args);

                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <!-- add your code which to display hear -->


                    <?php 
                        endwhile; 
                        wp_reset_query();
                    ?>
```